# How to Extract Specified Edges from an EdgeList

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the following edge list

```
edges = {N1003 -> N1003, N1003 -> N1099, N8911 -> N23122, 
  N34019 -> N36051, N1019 -> N36001, N36019 -> N36043, N3405 -> N3423,
   N36291 -> N36004}
```

I've tried various string argument to no avail. I'd like to extract just the edges in the above edgelist that contains the string N34 and N36. For example, I'm looking to just extract what would be the last 5 edges in the above edge list. The last 5 edges contain an N34 or an N36 in one end or both ends of the "a->"b" pair. Thoughts? Many thanks.

I've tried this ... it works ... but it is not efficient ...

```
Flatten[List[
  Select[edges, 
   And @@ {StringContainsQ[ToString@#[[1]], ""], 
      StringContainsQ[ToString@#[[2]], "N36"]} &],
  Select[edges, 
   And @@ {StringContainsQ[ToString@#[[1]], ""], 
      StringContainsQ[ToString@#[[2]], "N34"]} &],
  Select[edges, 
   And @@ {StringContainsQ[ToString@#[[1]], "34"], 
      StringContainsQ[ToString@#[[2]], ""]} &],
  Select[edges, 
   And @@ {StringContainsQ[ToString@#[[1]], "36"], 
      StringContainsQ[ToString@#[[2]], ""]} &]]]
```

Comment: Those are not actually strings. Are they supposed to be strings?

Comment: No they don't have to be strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
edges = {N1003 -> N1003, N1003 -> N1099, N8911 -> N23122, 
  N34019 -> N36051, N1019 -> N36001, N36019 -> N36043, N3405 -> N3423,
   N36291 -> N36004}
```

Turn whole edges into strings:

```
edges2 = ToString /@ edges;
```

Find ones with "N34" or "N36" then convert back to expressions:

```
ToExpression@Select[edges2, StringContainsQ[#, {"N34", "N36"}] &]
```

> {N34019 -> N36051, N1019 -> N36001, N36019 -> N36043, N3405 -> N3423,
> N36291 -> N36004}

Answer (score 3):

```
pred = Apply[Or] @* StringStartsQ["N34"|"N36"] @* Map[SymbolName] @* Apply[List];
```

#### 1.

Use `pred` with `Select`:

```
Select[pred] @ edges
```

[image]

#### 2.

Use `pred` with [`EdgeList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeList.html):

```
EdgeList[edges, _?pred]
```

[image]

Comment: MelaGo and kglr: These are both wonderfully efficient answers compared to mine ... thank u both very much ... I always learn from these correspondences and thank u for sharing your talents ...